# Built timer with no bugs - Wont launch (Python, tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I built a countdown timer with no bugs, however, it will not launch. In the shell it just says: 'Process finished with exit code 0' but it does not launch.

Here's my code(If its too long comment and I will add pastebin):

```
import tkinter

DEFAULT_GAP = 60 * 25


class study_timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.master, bg='white')
        self.mainframe.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.timer_text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.timer_text.trace('w', self.build_timer)
        self.time_left = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.time_left.set(DEFAULT_GAP)

        self.build_grid()
        self.build_banner()
        self.build_buttons()
        self.build_timer()

        self.update()

    def build_grid(self):
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

    def build_banner(self):
        banner = tkinter.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            bg='black',
            text='TIMER',
            fg='white',
            font=('Ravie Regular', 30)
        )
        banner.grid(
            row=0, column=0,
            stick='ew',
            padx=10, pady=10
        )
    def build_buttons(self):
        buttons_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mainframe)
        buttons_frame.grid(row=2,
                           column=0,
                           sticky='nsew',
                           padx=10, pady=10)
        buttons_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        buttons_frame.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

        self.start_button = tkinter.Button(
            buttons_frame,
            text='Start',
            command= self.start_timer
        )

        self.stop_button = tkinter.Button(
            buttons_frame,
            text='Stop',
            command=self.stop_timer
        )


        self.start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    def build_timer(self, *args):
        timer = tkinter.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            text=self.timer_text.get(),
            font=('Helvetica', 36)
        )
        timer.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def start_timer(self):
        self.time_left.set(DEFAULT_GAP)
        self.running = True
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self.start_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    def stop_timer(self):
        self.running = False
        self.stop_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self.start_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)

    def min_sec(self, seconds):
        return int(seconds/60), int(seconds%60)

    def update(self):
        time_left = self.time_left.get()

        if self.running and time_left:
            minutes, seconds = self.min_sec(time_left)
            self.time_left.set(time_left-1)

        else:
             self.stop_timer()
             self.master.after(1000, self.update)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            root = tkinter.Tk()
            timer = study_timer(root)
            root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you run python <name of your script> from command line with that script nothing is gonna happen cause it is just a class and no code that actually does anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the last part `if __name__ == "__main__":` and everything below that, two indents back.

Comment: Thanks I did that and received the following:line 94, in update
    `if self.running and time_left:
AttributeError: 'study_timer' object has no attribute 'running'`

Comment: Well you're calling update before start_timer which is where you declare running. So maybe you should start the timer before you run update or add self.running=False in __init__()

Comment: Where would I put the update? I removed self.updtae() and my gui worked but there was only the start and stop button and no timer or countdown. Sorry for all the questions i`m new to coding!

Comment: I didn't say to remove self.update(). Try add it again and also declare self.running = False somewhere before you call self.update(). I can't debug your code for you, you will have to figure out the errors yourself by banging your head against the wall a little - that's how you become a good programmer :)